# mysql show most recent `ip`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(`id`) as count 
 FROM `visitors` 
 WHERE `time` = max(`time`) 
 GROUP BY `ip` 
 ORDER BY `time` DESC";
```

This is my query for showing data from my visitors table grouping them by ip but I want to show the most recent time of that particualr ip;

For ex. if this ip: 145.46.78.241 is opened 10 times I want to show the latest one, I mean the greatest UNIX-timestamp.

```
#   ip               location             isp                           time

5   79.171.53.96    Tirana, Tirane, AL   AS30722 Vodafone Omnitel B.V.  58 minutes ago
11  46.252.36.216   AL                   AS52073 4ALB                   2 hours ago
2   79.171.53.100   Tirana, Tirane, AL   AS30722 Vodafone Omnitel B.V.  2 hours ago
```

Now for ex. ip=79.171.53.96 is opened more recently than 58 min ago and I want to display that one not the one that is opened 58 min ago.

My query is not working and I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object`

Comment: you can't use `SELECT *` with a `group by` clause if not added all columns. And an aggregate may not appear in the `WHERE` clause but in `HAVING`

Comment: It look like more a php error. Can we see you code?

Comment: Won't `where \`time\` = max(\`time\`)` just give you 1 row? The logic seems off, but that would also depend on the type of column for `time`.

Comment: Yes it gives me only one row.

Comment: I wish the duplicate finder worked better

Comment: So don't use that condition, instead select `MAX(time)` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ip, max(time) as 'Time', count(ip) as '#'
FROM visitors
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY max(time) DESC
```

in addition you can use

```
 max(location) as 'Location', max(isp) as 'ISP'
```

in `SELECT` statement if needed